# Wait for executable to finish running

Tags: windows, batch-file

Can you run two executables in a batch file and wait for the first process to end before starting the next?

Comment: That is the default behaviour, isn't it?

Comment: Do you mean that the first process should "successfully" end before starting the next?

Comment: @ Ravi Gummadi Yes, and if it fails it shouldn't run the next process

Comment: @Pekka it's only the default behaviour for console apps

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use start /wait:

```
:NOTEPAD
start /wait notepad.exe
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto NEXTITEM1
else goto QUIT

:NEXTITEM1
start /wait mplayer.exe
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto NEXTITEM2
else goto QUIT

:NEXTITEM2
start /wait explorer.exe
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto NEXTITEM3
else goto QUIT

:NEXTITEM3
REM You get the idea...

:QUIT
exit
```

In addition, use NT CMD rather than BAT (myscript.cmd).

In response to the comments, brackets removed from the above script around %ERRORLEVEL%.  The following seems to behave as expected:

```
:NOTEPAD
start /wait notepad.exe || goto QUIT

:NEXTITEM1
start /wait mplayer2.exe || goto QUIT

:NEXTITEM2
REM You get the idea...

:QUIT
exit
```

The statement after the double-pipe only executes if what is before it fails.

Comment: Why should I use cmd rather than bat? would that make a difference?

Comment: I've just found things to behave a little more reliably in Windows 2000+; script edited to include error-checking as requested in comments.

Comment: @Pillblast, there are a few very minor differences in execution between BAT and CMD as file extensions. Both are run by cmd.exe, the Windows Command Processor, though. In this case there is no difference at all.

Comment: nimizen: That code isn't going to work. You're comparing here the string "(0" to "0)". Guess how likely they are to be equal ... What you want is actually not to use the `%errorlevel%` pseudo-variable at all, unless you've made sure to unset it before use to avoid bugs due to shadowing. You also don't want to use `exit` there as it will kill your interactive console session if you use it in a batch file. To simply exit the batch file let it run to the end, use `exit /b` or `goto :eof`. Simple and more correct than the mess you have there.

Comment: Joey: The only problem I see here is you might need to use redirection to ensure you're returning the EXE exit code rather than the 'start' exit code.  Rather than just calling this a mess how about providing some alternative in code?  'Exit' is acceptable as there was no requirement to leave the console session open in the OP.  In addition, I remember reading somewhere that BAT extensions are executed in 16-bit VDM and CMD extensions are executed in 32-bit VDM which can have implications when accessing shared memory from other processes... not so minor.

Comment: A guy named Mark Zbikowski has at least [once](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win2000.cmdprompt.admin/msg/ad9066638815812c) answered a question about differences between the two file types.

Comment: @andiry I asked in this specific case why would i need to use cmd rather than bat because i couldn't see the reason.

Comment: @Pillblast: From how I've understood Zbikowski's answer, there doesn't seem to be any reason to prefer one over the other in this particular case. And generally I may from now on be choosing my batch scripts to have the `.bat` extension more often than `.cmd`, considering those distinctions, just to play safe. I mean, I don't expect to often need that kind of behaviour that is notable for `.cmd` scripts.

Comment: @nimizen: Joey's point about brackets in `IF`s is still valid regardless of cmd/bat distictions. The brackets there are treated as parts of the expressions being compared, so your script so far can only run notepad.exe and then it will quit in any case.

Comment: @Pillblast I read somewhere that .cmd  files offer an option to right click and run as admin, where .bat dont. forget where I saw that though

Answer (score 7):

one shorter way:

```
notepad.exe|more
```

even this can be used:

```
notepad|rem
```

though eventually with `more` you'll able to catch some output if there's any.And this is the reason it works - the piped command waits for input until the .exe is finished.

Comment: This should be the right answer, as the problem with using the "start /wait" command is that the ">NUL" redirection does not work any more