# Close console after closing a .txt file

Tags: windows, file, cmd, command

I've made a simple script that saves disk structure to a .txt file and then opens it. Is there any way to close the console automatically after closing that .txt file?

This is how my code looks. variables.cmd contains all of my variables declarations.

```
@echo off

call "%~dp0\variables.cmd" /b

%disk%:
cd /

echo Creating folders

md %loc_a%
md %loc_b%
md %loc_c%
md %lok_d%
md %loc_e%
md %loc_f% 

echo Folders created
echo %name% > %name%\%aa%_1.txt
echo %aa% > %lokalizacja_a%\%bb%_2.txt
echo %bb% > %lokalizacja_b%\%cc%_3.txt
echo %cc% > %lokalizacja_c%\%dd%_4.txt
echo %dd% > %lokalizacja_d%\%ee%_5.txt
echo %ee% > %lokalizacja_e%\%ff%_6.txt
echo %ff% > %lokalizacja_f%\%gg%_7.txt

cd %name%

set fileone= %aa%_1.txt


copy %icon1% %icon2%


echo [.ShellClassInfo] > %loc_a%\desktop.ini
echo IconFile=%dysk%:\%ikona2% >> %loc_a%\desktop.ini
echo IconIndex = 0 >> %loc_a%\desktop.ini
attrib +h +r -a &loc_a%\desktop.ini
attrib +r %loc_a%

start %name%\%aa%_1.txt

pause


rem I want to close this after I close %pause%\%aa%_1.txt
```

Comment: If you are working with the windows command line, or using a batch file script, you can use the "exit" command.

If you are using some other language for your script, please provide more information.

Comment: I am using the windows command line. The problem is that I want to have the console opened while I have .txt opened. It should be automatically closed after I close the .txt file.

Comment: Please could you edit your script into your original question, so that we can see what you have so far.

Comment: Also, consider looking at this question, as it seems very similar to what you are asking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375609/wait-for-executable-to-finish-running

Comment: Thanks. start /wait is exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
start %name%\%aa%_1.txt
pause
```

With:

```
start /wait %name%\%aa%_1.txt
REM No need for pause, as you want the script to exit when text is closed.
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed.